# How much ammo can a small ammo pouch and ammo crate replace?

Tags: battlefield-1

In Battlefield 1, the Support class can drop small ammo pouches and ammo crates to resupply themselves or other players. What is the resupply capacity of each? Does it depend upon the type of ammo that is replaced (pistol ammo vs grenades, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small pouch will restock **4 items in one single persons inventory**. Explosive items have a delay in restocking but still get restocked from that same single-use pouch. You don't even need to wait over the pouch - just grab it and run and it'll fill you up shortly after.

The crate will restock **20 units, split over whoever is in the 3.5m vicinity at the time**.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_one/comments/5ep7m7/facts_about_medic_and_ammo_cratespouches/)

> ### Ammo crate:
>
> - resupplies  20 units (since Dec. patch) (magazines, grenades, rocket gun ammo,...) over time then vanishes
> - 3.5 m radius
> - only one deployable at a time
> - vanishes 5.0 sec after support died
> - Syringe has no cooldown after two revives (since Dec. patch)
>
> ### Ammo pouch (little ammo kit):
>
> - resupplies 4 units instantly (some gadgets and grenades got "ready times" so they aren't usable instantly, but they are refilled
>     instantly and just not displayed as such)
> - those 4 units can be split among different weapons/gadgets if the highest priority weapon/gadget is full (see above in the general info
>     section) three deployable at a time, support carries two, then
>     replenish delay of 6 sec
> - vanishes 10.0 sec after support died

Comment: thanks. That is what I was looking for. +1 for pointing me to the source.